# startimagestream in flutter not working in web

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using camera to get  image stream in flutter.
I'm getting this error while start stream

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Assertion failed: 
file:///home/rahul/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub- 
cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.9.8+1/lib/src/camera_controller.dart:422:12
defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android ||
    default
```

here is my code

```
// ignore_for_file: unused_local_variable, avoid_print, unused_element, unused_import, 
   depend_on_referenced_packages, must_be_immutable, sized_box_for_whitespace
   import 'dart:async';

   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
   import 'package:heart_rate_app/networking/firebase_api.dart';
   import 'package:heart_rate_app/networking/heart_rate_api.dart';
   import 'dart:io' as io;
   import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
   import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
   import 'package:cross_file_image/cross_file_image.dart';

   import '../utils/color_detector.dart';

   class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    HomePage({Key? key, required this.cameras}) : super(key: key);
   List<CameraDescription> cameras;

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
  }

    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
    List<CameraDescription> cameras = [];
      late CameraController controller;



 @override
void initState() {
super.initState();
controller = CameraController(widget.cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.high);
controller.initialize().then((value) {
  if (!mounted) {
    return;
  }
  setState(() {});
});
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
   controller.dispose();
   super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
     return Container();
   }
   return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        child: CameraPreview(controller,),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 20,),
     
   
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            controller.startImageStream((image) {

            });
        
          },
          child: const Text("capture")),
    
    ],
  ),
   );


 }


}
```

here is the error screenshot from the chrome desktop. and I also tried on my phone chrome (android) getting the same error.

...............................................................

please provide some solution for this. thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

camera_web  plugin is under development.

Missing implementation of camera_web
The web implementation of the camera is missing the following features:

1. Exposure mode, point and offset
2. Focus mode and point
3. Sensor orientation
4. Image format group
5. Streaming of frames

Answer (score 1):

Just add the https://pub.dev/packages/camera_web. package in yout `pubspec.yaml` file.

It will automatically add the web support.

Comment: I have tried but not working. camera_web: ^0.2.1+6.

but I'm already using flutter_camera: ^0.1.1 . it support web also

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter for web. You can use `takePicture()` with a timer instead. The method will return a blob, which does not affect the performance.

Code snippet:

```dart
Future<void> decodeFrames() async {
    if (_controller == null || !_isCameraReady) return;

    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 20), () async {
      if (_controller == null || !_isCameraReady) return;

      XFile file = await _controller!.takePicture();
      
      // Your image processing code

      decodeFrames();
    });
  }
```

### Try My Source Code and Online Demo

- https://github.com/yushulx/flutter-camera-document-scanner/tree/main
- https://yushulx.me/flutter-camera-document-scanner